# CSS Animation working in Chrome not in Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, safari, transition

I want a div when absolute position to change place with a css3 animation.
The trick works on Chomre (webkit) but not on Safari for iDevices.

In Safari it did the following:
Appear slowly
Change position SUDDENLY (smothly in chrome)
Disappear slowly

What can be? Thanks in advice

```
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {opacity: 0; bottom: 2px; right: 5%;}
25%  {opacity: 1; bottom: 2px; right: 5%;}
75%  {opacity: 1; bottom: 40%; right: 5%;}
100% {opacity: 0; bottom: 40%; right: 5%;}
}
```

I have tried 0%=from and 100%=to and get the same behavior

EDIT -> SOLVED
*
*Safari dont let me make bottom: 2px; right: 5%; to bottom: 40%; right: 5%;
*
*All values must be same type, percent or px
*
*This will work:

```
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {opacity: 0; bottom: 1%; right: 5%;}
25%  {opacity: 1; bottom: 1%; right: 5%;}
75%  {opacity: 1; bottom: 40%; right: 5%;}
100% {opacity: 0; bottom: 40%; right: 5%;}
}
```

Comment: You can answer your own question and then accept the answer. This way the question is no longer marked as unanswered.

Comment: I think I didnt do it cause the system says i was too new for voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {opacity: 0; bottom: 1%; right: 5%;}
25%  {opacity: 1; bottom: 1%; right: 5%;}
75%  {opacity: 1; bottom: 40%; right: 5%;}
100% {opacity: 0; bottom: 40%; right: 5%;}
}
```